# Keeping currently selected node at top of treeview

Tags: vb6

I have a treeview (TVWDB) which has several node, children and grandchildren.  Depending on the user these can be shown as just the parent node, or with the children or even grandchildren displayed.

The user steps through this using a button which advances down the tree at the level they have selected (ie if a child is selected then it will step through each child).

Im looking for a way that when the selected item drops down that node is shown at the top of the tree (if there are parents then it should actually be the parent node which is shown.

I keep looking at .Ensurevisible and Getvisible count but this seems to work on the 1st attempt but then start jumping around on each subsequent advance.

Comment: Is TVWDB a third-party control? Or else what is it?

Comment: No this is the standard treeview control, I've just called this instance of the control TVWDB